# Samsung S8 Nougat Always On Display (AOD) api

Tags: android

Does anyone know if Google provides an API to configure the AON on the S8 and similar devices?
On the Display documentation I didn't find anything.
I was wondering if someone had experience creating app that make changes like, adding text, positioning image adding an app icon etc (I know the stock features do provide some of these features but I wanted to know if it was possible to do this by creating a third party app)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I came across a guy who has been doing some development on the Always On Display. On XDA forum he has an app that does exactly what I am looking for and he has been kind enough to provide some further info.

> It's an overlay targeting the AOD, you can build overlays either by
>   manually adding code with Apkeditor (app) or build an overlay with
>   Android Studio, my mods are built with Android Studio.
>
> There's a substratum template that should help you themeing apps.
>   (With overlays) https://github.com/substratum/template